# Sendpulse SMS using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, xmlhttprequest

This surely is a trivial question.
I am new to this and trying to use Sendpulse API in VBA. It has a method to obtain authorization: https://sendpulse.com/integrations/api#libraries

image of the Authorization API section

[image: 1]

My VBA code is as follows:

```
    Dim URL As String
    Dim xmlHttp As Object
    Dim data As String
    Set xmlHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

    URL = "https://api.sendpulse.com/oauth/access_token"
    data = "grant_type=client_credentials , client_id=-redacted-, client_secret=-redacted--"
    xmlHttp.Open "POST", URL, False                 'False means wait for response after send
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    xmlHttp.send data
    Debug.Print xmlHttp.ResponseText
```

I receive

> ': responseText : "{"error":"unsupported_grant_type","error_description":"The
> authorization grant type is not supported by the authorization
> server.","hint":"Check that all required parameters ha"*

The tech support verifies the input parameters work using "postman". I am rather sure it is a VBA syntax problem. tech supp doesn't know didleysquat about excel/VBA.

I will appreciate it if an expert eye can tell what is wrong.

I've tried all combinations of quotes in the data=... above e.g.
`data = "grant_type=""client_credentials"" , client_id=""xxxx"" , client_secret=""xxxx"""`

and nothing worked. I even tried colons in place of =. Perhaps the header is wrong? (ps. they tell me header is not needed, w/o it still the same)

Comment: You have to send the exact formatting of the string as in the sample

Answer (score 1):

Carefully build your data string:

```vb
' Json skeleton.
Const DataMask As String = "{""grant_type"":""{0}"",""client_id"":""{1}"",""client_secret"":""{2}""}"

Dim Data       As String

' Json data fill.
Data = DataMask
Data = Replace(Data, "{0}", "client_credentials")
Data = Replace(Data, "{1}", "237b4af9c99d0f89bdbd876dcd5a0000")
Data = Replace(Data, "{2}", "a99e7d506d3701c5c04de3db1913eeee")

' Json check.
Debug.Print Data
```

Result:

```
{"grant_type":"client_credentials","client_id":"237b4af9c99d0f89bdbd876dcd5a0000","client_secret":"a99e7d506d3701c5c04de3db1913eeee"}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I tried what you suggested and as you indicated the result I see looks like this which is a nice way to do it. The change is enclosure in curly brackets.       {"grant_type":"client_credentials","client_id":"gobldygook1","client_secret":"gobldygook2"}          Alas the results is the same: no cigar! I doubt there is anyone further anything can say :(( . Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks to Gustav and his curly brackets, PLUS the fact that the header needs to specify this is a JSON message. At first the tech support told me there is no need for a header, and he MAY have been right if using some other script language they know. The next tech support fellow said to add the header back in:            xmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"     and the server responded as intended. I will post the entire code here if and when I get the SMSsend to work as well.

Comment: Yes, ` "application/json"` is normally what to use, but I don't know about SendPulse, so they might have set it differently.